# Protocol for remote logging of temperature, gas/electricity consumption

Tags: api, networking, logging, messaging, sensors

So, I'm managing a series of rented holiday homes, which all have dynamic IP, ADSL Internet connections.

We've wanted to keep track of a few types of data, e.g. per-room electricity usage, hot water temperature, thermostat setting, gas usage, network bandwidth usage, etc etc, and keep these centrally so we can perform analytics and graph them in real-time.

I'm comfortable building the hardware required to log these variables every 1-5 seconds and get them into e.g. a Raspberry Pi, but I'm wondering what kind of framework would be suitable for transferring and storing the data on the server side.

My initial thought was something like SNMP, but a) this doesn't seem designed for non-network uses, b) it's not very secure, and c) I'm looking for something agent-to-server (so I don't have to know the IP of the agent, and it'll also traverse NAT, so I can have multiple devices logging different things on the same network.)

My second thought was something using a REST API, but making potentially hundreds of API calls per second via different TCP connections seems a bit wasteful.

I came across [Cubism](http://square.github.io/cube/) but this seems to have the same disadvantages as some sort of REST API; there's a lot of redundant data transmitted every connection, if I were to send the data every 5 seconds per sensor.

Names like AMQP and MQTT come up, though none of these seem particularly suited (natively) to travelling over the public Internet without configuring VPNs etc.

Thoughts?

[This doesn't seem like a particularly niche problem, now I think about it - weather logging, share price, etc etc... although this is probably a smaller interval]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an geospatial/environment monitoring background and can tell you something about two major standards which are used today in environmental/infrastructural (electricity and water supply networks) monitoring sensor networks.

1. Proprietary one: Most sensors simply store time series measurements in their own local data format. A server process calls every sensor from time to time to gather the time series data (in most cases via a simple GPRS uplink), transforms it into an exchange Format and then stores it into a centralized database where you can work with the data. One of the industry leader companies is [Kisters AG](http://www.kisters.net/wiski.html) and their exchange format ZRXP. So this is simply storing time series data in an ASCII Format (i.e.ZRXP), and import that into a database by calling the sensor over any connection.
2. Open Geospatial Standard: [Sensor Observation Service](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/SOS) and [SensorML](http://www.sensorml.com/index.html) which I think does more fit your needs, because these are Web Service Specifications whilst the proprietary stuff above is a complete system solution built by one vendor. There exists a nearly ready to use java reference implementation of SOS provided by [52 north](http://52north.org/communities/sensorweb/sos/) which should be easily runnable on a Pi. Although the SOS specification has a very strong geospatial background, that does not mean,that it can't be adopted for your purpose I think. At least SensorML should give you some ideas.